# Open Excel document from Access issues

Tags: vba, ms-access, file-io

In my database I manage different Excel files. There's a button in a Report which allows to open those files, and to do it I use this linse of code (runs the code at click on the button):

```
    Dim str_file As String
    str_file = "C:\[directory of the file]"
    Application.FollowHyperlink str_file
```

It works, and opens the file I want. The problem is that it does not set the excel program as active, when it opens the file it shows very quickly the file but for something I don't know Excel application is hiden and Access application is active. I I've experienced some problems with popup forms that because it's a popup, you can't set an active window different from the popup, but this problem solves if you close the popup before setting an active form. I've tried also lines like these above but they don't work also:

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
```

Comment: Is there any code that runs after Followhyperlink? Best step though and check, because it works fine for me. BTW You could also look at WScript.Shell

Comment: @Remou I have a line with "exit sub" and the error code after the DollowHyperlink. I'll take a look Wscript.shell

Comment: That does not cause a problem for me. Do you get the same problem when you simply run followhyperlink with no trimmings from a module?

Comment: Yes I have the same problem. But I found the problem. I'll post it

Comment: Good, looking forward.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The code in Access works well, it does what it's supposed to do. The excel files I have are ".xlsm", because I need to run some code when the file is saved, I need to update some fields on Access database. So I needed to call Access from excel, and this code runs when the file opens. So I run Excel from Access and then Access from Excel. I hope that this helps someone with that problem. Remember: if you have problems whith opening files from Access and your excel files can run code, check that all runs when you really need.